# How do Alliance team-ups work?

Tags: marvel-puzzle-quest

When I send or request team-ups from my alliance, which spell will they get?
Can they get a spell I don't own with my character?
Which rank will the spell have?
What level will be the team-up I sent, the same as my character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a team-up, your alliance mate gets a spell chosen randomly among those you have on that character, so if you have just one ability on that hero that's the one your friend gets.

The rank and level of the spell is the same as the one that's on your character.